# Right way to initialize and introduce vector of arrays in one line?

Tags: c++

What are the right methods?
How to avoid the 3 errors?

I tried the followings:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct s_4{double x,z,k,wsize;};
typedef vec4 vector <array<double,4>>;  //ERROR #1

void main()
{
    vector <s_4> s1;
    vector <array<double,4>> d1;

    s1.push_back(*new (s_4){10.0,11,1,0.25e-3});  //OK
    d1.push_back(*new (array<double,4>){10.0,11,1,0.25e-3});  //OK
    d1.push_back(*new (double[4]){10.0,11,1,0.25e-3});  //ERROR #2
    vector <array<double,4>> d2{11,12,13,14.1};   //ERROR #3
    getchar();
}
```

It is like it is very difficult to use large arrays in vectors

Comment: And the errors are ...?

Comment: `*new` is a memory leak

Comment: `new` alone is ugly, but `*new` is by far the worst... sorry ... DONT DO THIS

Comment: @mathengineer For the three errors, I hope that the compiler is telling you what you shouldn't do with that. *"It is like it is very difficult to use large arrays in vectors"*: This will happen when do not know, how to use it. I suggest you to read a bit vector and its constructors.

Comment: Thank you, I was not happy with the *new. In order to not use it anymore is possible to assign values to a struct in another way than: s2=*new (s_4){20,30,50,101};   ??

Answer (score 3):

The correct code is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct s_4{double x,z,k,wsize;};
typedef vector <array<double,4>> vec4;

int main()
{
    vector <s_4> s1;
    vector <array<double,4>> d1;

    s1.push_back({10.0,11,1,0.25e-3});
    d1.push_back({10.0,11,1,0.25e-3});
    d1.push_back({10.0,11,1,0.25e-3});
    vector <array<double,4>> d2{{11,12,13,14.1}};
    return 0;
}
```

Your first error in the typedef is that the name of the typedef comes last.

Your first three push_backs were leaking memory, you don't need to name the type when initialising.

The second error is because a c array can't be converted directly to a std::array.

The last needs two sets of braces, one to initialise the vector and one to initialise each array.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Alan's answer:

Why are you trying to allocate your arrays on the heap? You could place your arrays on the stack and use initializer lists:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::array<double,4>> data = {
        {10.0,11,1,0.25e-3},
        {10.0,11,1,0.25e-3},
        {10.0,11,1,0.25e-3},
        {11,12,13,14.1}
    };
}
```

However, initializer lists are a C++11 feature so you may compile with `-std=c++11`:

```
g++ -g -Wall -O2 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
```

Furthermore you should avoid `using namespace std`, as this may cause problems if you use additional libraries that implement for example vectors for mathematical calculations.

Comment: As Alan already answered the question, and the author mentioned, that he/she had problems initializing large arrays, I added this as addition to Alan's answer.

Comment: Yes, alan solved in one post almost all of my troubles with vectors. Phidelux, I made different functions that add vectors so I can not initialize all of them at once